# Add easing effect with skrollr/jquery on page load?

Tags: jquery, skrollr

When my page loads I would like to trigger a small easing effect where the background elements seem to "fall into place".  This would happen before the user interacts with the page.

I think I can handle to skrollr animations I just need to know what to use to trigger this effect.  For example, I'm guessing I would start with:

```
$document.ready({ function() {
   ----action here----
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

$(document).ready(function(){

```
//animations code here. But if you want to a delay for it you can use the function setTimeOut (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).
setTimeout(function(){animate()},1000); // fires the function one second delayed
```

});

Hope this helps